# Shortcut function misbehaving?

Tags: 16.04, shortcut-keys, configuration, desktop-environments, function-keys

I have a Asus laptop with Ubuntu 16.04, It has a function shortcut (<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f7</kbd>) which I used to turn off the display.

I connected it to an external display via `HDMI`, removed the cable, shut it down. but now after a fresh boot It locks my account instead and not turning the display off!

Any idea or suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood the problem correct....
You are saying that the behavior of fn+f7 is changed after you attached and detached your device to an external display.

Here are some pointers to find out what fn+f7 is mapped to after this action
https://superuser.com/questions/428945/defining-keyboard-shortcuts-involving-the-fn-key

There are at least two possibilities here
1) When connected to external display, fn+f7 key can't turn that display off (depends upon display type) so it rather changes to display lockout. Maybe you don't remember and you shut it down in that state and so it stays in that stays (some persistent configuration?).
2) fn+f7 is multiplexed at the keyboard hw level and may have a HW bug (passive electronics component used) where attaching to HDMI modified one of it's state holding. This is very less likely and should be cleared after a complete power shutdown and a wait before restart.

Comment: I have a keyboard `fn`+`f8` which is for setting external display states, in windows (which I used a couple years ago) it showed the mode it is in as a notification, e.g. it is mirroring, just external or just internal but in ubuntu it didn't show that so I don't remember in which state I turned it off.

Comment: I needed some more clarification and details but have the bounty anyway.

Comment: As for me Fn+f7 stopped working after some Linux kernel update. I did not connect and disconnect any external display to my ASUS UX305L. The HW hotkey simply stopped working. It was working in login screen, in user session etc.

Just in case other HW related hotkeys as audio, touchpad, brightness all work OK.

Comment: @SergeySergeyev, did you find any solution?

Comment: @Masked Man, I just checked Fn+F7 at system BIOS (before Linux kernel bootload) - it operates as expected, screen blanks. During boot (even before login and Gnome) the key stops to switch the screen off. I suspect the Kernel or low level system configuration is responsible for this issue.

Comment: @SergeySergeyev, if this is the case how should I diagnose and solve the issue?

Comment: @MaskedMan

Can you run xev and check what codes are printed in your system when you press and release fn+f7?

Then repeat the experiment while booting off a live disk (I am assuming your Fn+F7 works in that case properly as intended).

Compare the two and see if the codes are changed.

Then off you go to exploring xkb.